# Cointegration and trend stationarity

Tags: time-series, trend, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Cointegration relationship is typically studied with integrated time series (that is, difference stationary time series) and when they have the same order of integration, it is possible that you find a cointegration relationship between the time-series. But is cointegration possible between two trend stationary time series ? And if so, can we model further and build a VECM or ECM whose long-run relationship is made out of trend stationary series ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is simply not how cointegration is defined. For cointegration, there must be stochastic trends (unit root processes) to begin with; deterministic trends won't cut it. When you have series with deterministic trends, you do not need a (V)ECM. A VAR with a time trend will do the job, so any error-correction term would be superfluous.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: I wouldn’t restrict stochastic trends to unit root processes only(even though the most common). Any shared stochastic trend can be a topic of cointegration.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, I suppose you are right. Are you hinting in the direction of fractional cointegration? Or what other stochastic, non-unit root trends do you have in mind?

Comment: OK. An I(2) process actually has two unit roots, so I would still call it a unit root process, but I guess that could be debated.